# Other agencies for passport

Tags: regulations

I want to know if and where I can quickly (within two weeks) get a passport from a non-governmental agency.

Comment: If you see non-goverment sources offering to get you a passport, often all they do is fill in the government forms (with information that you gave them) then charge you double.

Comment: What country of citizenship (looks like USA); what country of residence? Where/how did you apply?  Passports are always issued by a governmental agency; in some countries, in some cases, private organisations can help (for a fee) prepare the required documents - but cannot issue the passport.

Answer (score 6):

Passports must be issued by a [sovereign government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereignty).

The exceptions being a [United Nations Passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_laissez-passer), EU Laissez-Passer, and other supranational entities.